# Is there a way to see the ERR diagram lines in color?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I used 'MySql Workbench' to generate the ERR diagram of an existing DB. It generated fine and I see the relations in colorful arrows if I click on a particular table.  But those colors just go off if I click outside the table or try to export the diagram into a PDF.

Here is a screenshot where the green highlighted line shows up just when I click on the table.  Is there a way to keep these colored lines while exporting the diagram into PDF?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors only visualize certain properties while a relationship is highlighted. Since this is bound to the highlighting (i.e. hovering with the mouse over a relationship) it's not exported or printed. However, IIRC there's a feature request already asked exactly for this wish too. So one day it might be implemented. For now you cannot have the colors in the printouts.